# Clear DisplayObject() without giving object name

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to do a flash application that when the first button clicked, the displayObject function will display the image. When the second button clicked, the previous holder need to be clear all the object inside and this is the part that i stuck at. Any solution?

```
function showOppo (e:Event):void
{
    if(holder_1.stage)
    {
    holder_1 = new MovieClip();
    holder_2 = new MovieClip();
    holder_3 = new MovieClip();
    }
    holder_1.x = 37.6;
    holder_1.y = 133.05;
    holder_2.x = 458.55;
    holder_2.y = 133.05;

    Of9.scaleX = 1;
    Of9.scaleY = 1;
    Ofx.scaleX = 1;
    Ofx.scaleY = 1;

    holder_1.addChild(Of9);
    holder_2.addChild(Ofx);

    stage.addChild(holder_1);
    stage.addChild(holder_2);

    stage.setChildIndex(holder_1,1);
    stage.setChildIndex(holder_2,1);
}
function showsamsung (e:Event):void
{
    if(holder_1.stage)
    {
    holder_1 = new MovieClip();
    holder_2 = new MovieClip();
    holder_3 = new MovieClip();
    }
    holder_1.x = 37.6;
    holder_1.y = 133.05;
    holder_2.x = 458.55;
    holder_2.y = 133.05;

    Sgn9.scaleX = 1;
    Sgn9.scaleY = 1;
    Ss10.scaleX = 1;
    Ss10.scaleY = 1;

    holder_1.addChild(Sgn9);
    holder_2.addChild(Ss10);

    stage.addChild(holder_1);
    stage.addChild(holder_2);

    stage.setChildIndex(holder_1,1);
    stage.setChildIndex(holder_2,1);
}
```

Inside the code i use `new MovieClip()` but when 2nd button clicked and nothing happen. After 2nd button clicked, i go back and click 1st button again, the function of 2nd displayed.

Comment: Where is the function for this _"the displayObject **function** will display the image"_?? (2) What is the click function for first button? and for second button?? (3) Are `sgn9`and `ss10` etc all supposed to be images?? (4) No need for `new MovieClip` just re-use existing ones.

Comment: (1) i though that the holder is the displayObject function since i search on internet and that is what it shows to me. 
(2) The click function is working well and here is the function `btnoppo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,showOppo);` the first click and the second is this `btnsamsung.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,showsamsung);`
(3) those are the name of images i use for temporary so the name will be weird.
(4) i try to find out how to delete the existing child of each holder since if not, all those image will stack together

Comment: i had tried set it as null, remove holder from stage, new movieclip() But all these not working. Because i got other buttons so the child in each holder will be dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"I try to find out how to delete the existing child of each holder since if not, all those image will stack together"*

Yes, when you `addChild` it's like telling Flash to *`"paste this on a new layer inside the target"`*. Each layer is called a depth level. You can access the specific layer/depth by using `getChildAt(x)` where `x` is the layer number (first=`0`, second=`1`, third=`2` etc..)

Example:
Say you have one holder (*eg:* `holder_1`) for showing all images.

- 1) First time you'll addChild an image using `holder_1.addChild(pic1);`
   
  so now `pic1` exists at (layer) **level 0** inside target of`holder_1`.
- 2) Adding a second image with `holder_1.addChild(pic2);`
   
  so now `pic2` exists at (layer) **level 1** inside target of`holder_1`.

Now two Images are stacked up on different layers inside same container. How to fix? Consider this logic:

```
holder_1.addChild(pic2); //add pic2 into holder (at level 0)
holder_1.removeChildAt(0); //remove anything at level 0 (...is pic2)
holder_1.addChild(pic1); //add different pic1 into holder (at level 0)
```

Your code could try something like this:

```
holder_1 = new MovieClip();
holder_2 = new MovieClip();
holder_3 = new MovieClip();

holder_1.x = 37.6;  holder_2.x = 458.55;

//# give multiple VARS the same value   
holder_1.y = holder_2.y = 133.05;

stage.addChild(holder_1);
stage.addChild(holder_2);

btnoppo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,showOppo);
btnsamsung.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,showsamsung);

function showOppo (e:Event):void
{
    //# set multiple at once to value = 1
    Of9.scaleX = Of9.scaleY = Ofx.scaleX = Ofx.scaleY = 1;

    //# check if already has image & remove it
    if(holder_1.getChildAt(0) != null) { holder_1.removeChildAt(0); }
    if(holder_2.getChildAt(0) != null) { holder_2.removeChildAt(0); }

    holder_1.addChild(Of9); holder_2.addChild(Ofx);

}
function showsamsung (e:Event):void
{
    Sgn9.scaleX = Sgn9.scaleY = Ss10.scaleX = Ss10.scaleY = 1;

    //# check if already has image & remove it
    if(holder_1.getChildAt(0) != null) { holder_1.removeChildAt(0); }
    if(holder_2.getChildAt(0) != null) { holder_2.removeChildAt(0); }

    holder_1.addChild(Sgn9); holder_2.addChild(Ss10);

}
```

Comment: Cool, i had never think about that. :D
Thanks for helping to solve the problem.

Comment: if you want to remove everything in the holder, you could also just call `holder_1.removeChildren();` if flashplayer 11 or later is used